# HAAst terminating with exit code 158

Tags: asterisk, ubuntu-16.04, high-availability

I'm just trying to do a POC test with Telium's HAAst before we offer it to a customer, but I've stalled before I start the haast daemon. Currently I have a single VM with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Digium's basic Asterisk 13 installation. I've configured haast.conf, it seems good, but I cannot start haast daemon, it stops after a few seconds. Here is the relevant log output:

```
General, HAAst version 2.3.2.1 starting as daemon under process ID 2409

Controller, Local peer HAAst state changing to service start

License, License file not found. Switching to Free Edition

General, Settings contained 0 information; 0 warning; and 0 error messages.

Asterisk Controller, Unable to located executable to control Asterisk

Controller, Local peer HAAst state changing to service stop

Controller, Stopped

General, HAAst terminating with exit code 158 (failure to find asterisk control files) after running for 2 seconds
```

It seems, haast misses the event controller to start Asterisk daemon, unfortunately it didn't contain the installation package. I've tried to make these files (asterisk.start & asterisk.stop) based on the other sample event files, I've set the executable bit, I've wrote the shebang to the first line based on the installation guide, but nothing helped.

Is somebody experienced about this case?

Thanks, Zsolt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that High Availability for Asterisk (HAAst) is unable to find the service/executable file needed to control Asterisk.  Since the 'distribution' setting in the [asterisk] stanza of the haast.conf file is it to 2 (Digium Asterisk), it means there's a problem with the Asterisk service file.

Ubuntu 16 uses systemd so have you installed Digium's asterisk.service (systemd) file?  If you chose to install an initd service file for Asterisk instead then you may have to explicitly tell HAAst which to look for.  If you installed neither then that's your problem.  The maker of HAAst (Telium) has a support forum where this topic is addressed ([click here](https://telium.io/en/topic/problem-starting-asterisk-on-systemdinitd-system/)).

The pre and post Asterisk event handlers are available in the commercial versions of HAAst only - so that won't help (but it's also the wrong way to solve the problem).  There are also a few Ubuntu specific topics on the support forum [https://www.telium.io/haast](https://telium.io/en/high-availability-for-asterisk/forums/) in case that helps.

If you can't find an Asterisk systemd service file here's a sample:

```
[Unit]
Description=Asterisk PBX and telephony daemon
Documentation=man:asterisk(8)
Wants=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=asterisk
Group=asterisk
ExecStart=/usr/bin/asterisk -f -C /etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf
ExecStop=/usr/bin/asterisk -rx 'core stop now'
ExecReload=/usr/bin/asterisk -rx 'core reload'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Just save that file as 'asterisk.service' and place in /etc/systemd/system/ and ensure permissions match other service/unit files.

Comment: Thanks very much, it was the issue! I've used initd instead of systemd to control Asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

Haast configuration is missing or not correct:

> Unable to located executable to control Asterisk

Comment: Yes, I see, but HAAst isn't contains any configuration option for this. This is a standard Asterisk compiled from source, HAAst needs to know the location of the executable. The only configurable option is the Asterisk distribution option, what is Digium's basic package option, as default.

Comment: So what you want me say you? File a bug to either asterisk or HAAst team. Or check your path to executable.